# sed extract part of string from a file

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I've ben trying to extract only part of string from a file looking like this:

```
str1=USER_NAME
str2=justAstring
str3=https://product.org/v-4.5-bin.zip
str4=USER_HOME
```

I need to extract ONLY the version - in this case: `4.5`

I did it by grep and then sed but now the output is `4.5-bin.zip`

```
-> grep str3 file.txt
str3=https://product.org/v-4.5-bin.zip
-> echo str3=https://product.org/v-4.5-bin.zip | sed -n "s/^.*v-\(\S*\)/\1/p"
4.5-bin.zip
```

What should I do in order to remove also the `-bin.zip` at the end?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples, please try following `sed` code.

```
sed -n '/^str3=/s/.*-\([^-]*\)-.*/\1/p' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Using `sed`'s `-n` option which will STOP printing of values by default, to only print matched part. In main program checking condition if line starts from `str3=` then perform substitution there. In substitution catching everything between 1st `-` and next `-` in a capturing group and substituting whole line with it by using `\1` and printing the matched portion only by using `p` option.

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Using GNU `grep` you could try following `grep` program.

```
grep -oP '^str3=.*?-\K([^-]*)' Input_file
```

---

---

***3rd solution:*** Using `awk` program for getting expected output as per shown smaples.

```
awk -F'-' '/^str3=/{print $2}'  Input_file
```

---

---

***4th solution:*** Using `awk`'s `match` function to get expected results with help of using `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` variables which get set once a TRUE match is found by match function.

```
awk 'match($0,/^str3=.*-/){split(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),arr,"-");print arr[2]}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the version contains just digits and dots, replace `\S` by `[0-9.]`. Also, match the remaining characters outside of the capture group to get it removed.

```
sed -n 's/^.*v-\([0-9.]*\).*/\1/p'
```